# R using apply for string comparisons

Tags: r, apply

Im trying to use `apply` to compare the distance between a grid of text
The idea would be to try and then parallelize the operation using the `parallel` function in R

When i run the below code i get the error

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (newX[, i])
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
d <- iris
my_grid <- expand.grid(unique(d$Species), unique(d$Species), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
apply(my_grid, MARGIN =  1, FUN = levenshteinSim, str1 = Var1, str2 = Var2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function in `apply` is not properly defined, can you try this

```
apply(my_grid, MARGIN =  1, FUN = function(V) levenshteinSim(V[1],V[2]))
```